# 404 error page not showing when using grails spring security 2 plugin

Tags: grails

I've upgraded to from the springsecurity 1.2 plugin to 2.0.  Now when I enter an invalid page into the browser I get directed to the 500 error page, not the 404 error page.  Is that how it's supposed to work?  I'm using the default reject rules:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false
```

and my 404 urlmapping looks like:

```
"404"(view:'/error/404')
```

Comment: did you able to solve this problem? I am facing it too.